# Java exceptions without the code to carry on

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to make a program which allows the user to enter 2 integers (marks). 
In case the user doesn't enter an integer, I am creating a try and catch code.

The problem is that after I try to enter letters instead of numbers, there is an error coming out but the program carries on, saying that I didn't pass. How do I let the program stop after saying to the user that he entered a wrong mark?

Here is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    try{
        myCalculator.setCWK(Integer.parseInt(courseEnter));
        myCalculator.setExam(Integer.parseInt(examEnter));
    }
    catch (Exception a){
        System.out.print("System error");
    }
    displayArea.setText("" + myCalculator.calculateModuleMark());
    if(myCalculator.hasPasssed()==true)
    {
        displayArea.setText(myCalculator.getModuleCode() + "Congratulations! You have PASSED! With a score of " +  myCalculator.calculateModuleMark() + "%");   
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);

    }
    else
    {
        displayArea.setText("I am sorry");
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the program to "stop" after a certain statement, `System.exit(0)` is your friend. So, in your catch statement, you could have

```
catch (Exception a){
    System.out.print("System error");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Note that this is different than `return`, as `System.exit(0)` will completely stop your program flow, not just this specific method.

Answer (score 0):

After printing out an error simply type `return`.

Answer (score 0):

The `try...catch` blocks means

if an error occurs in the `try` instruction block, execute the `catch` instruction block

In your case, you're not exiting the function in your `catch` block, so it will carry on.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling is essentially done to prevent the code from exiting abruptly without any error message.

You can just call `System.exit(1)` after `System.out.print("System error")`.

Note: `System.exit(0)` means program terminated as expected while any other error code within bracket means there was an error.

So, now your code will be:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    try{
    myCalculator.setCWK(Integer.parseInt(courseEnter));
    myCalculator.setExam(Integer.parseInt(examEnter));
    }
    catch (Exception a){
        System.out.print("System error");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    displayArea.setText("" + myCalculator.calculateModuleMark());
    if(myCalculator.hasPasssed()==true)
    {
        displayArea.setText(myCalculator.getModuleCode() + "Congratulations! You have PASSED! With a score of " +  myCalculator.calculateModuleMark() + "%");   
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);

    }
    else
    {
        displayArea.setText("I am sorry");
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

    }
}
```